# Is a virus forwarding me to this website called "home.clear.com"?

Tags: browser, virus, website

Whenever I try to access a website, I am forwarded to `http://home.clear.com`.

In Firefox, a warning will come up that says:

> home.clear.com uses an invalid security certificate.  The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided. (error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)

In Chrome and IE, no warning comes up and I am taken to the `home.clear.com`. I have run Norton Anti-Virus to no avail as well as another spyware programs (Hitman, I think).

I have recently installed an external Netgear network adapter because I was having connection problems at my new residence and the new adapter seemed to solve the issue until this problem popped up.

A few weeks ago I clicked on a Facebook click-jacking type scam but haven't had any issues until now.

I looked over this question but couldn't solve the problem: [Browsers forwarding to random website automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/149040/browsers-forwarding-to-random-website-automatically)

Comment: You can also contact your service provider and ask them to reset your connection.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a virus/spyware. If you have a notebook which uses an Intel WiMax adapter (Several Toshiba models, specifically), it will direct you to home.clear.com to sign up for Clear WiMax service if you attempt to use the WiMax portion of the device. If you're connected to a wireless access point, it may be hooked up to a WiMax modem exhibiting the same behaviour (Service inactive).

Regarding the security certificate error, that could be numerous things. Check your clock and calendar to confirm you have the correct date/time/timezone set. If you're not connected to a functioning internet connection, you could be receiving the certificate error because your browser can't verify the revocation status of the certificate.

Comment: wow thanks. i disabled the wimax adapter and i can now access the internutz again. so what is this? should i remove it entirely from my computer? why now is this a problem?

Comment: @Jed: Just keep it turned off until you actually decide to sign up for WiMAX. Your wireless network card management software should allow you separate control of Wi-Fi and WiMAX.

Comment: @Jed I believe the WiMax chip is on by default, it sounds like you just went from a stable network connection to an unstable one.